# How to setup OpenVPN server on windows in a simple way?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to setup OpenVPN **server** on Windows 10. It's only for testing purpose. So I want to set it up, **play with it via Management Interface** and then remove. No certificates, no security because I'll only play with on my local machine.

I've installed it to c:\programm files. In the documentation it doesn't say how to actually set it up. I suppose I should copy the file "server.ovpn" from "sample-config" to "config". Is that so? Why does it have the extenstion "ovpn" instead of ".conf"? Should I change it or what? What should I do next?

I copied "server.ovpn"  to the folder "config", restarted the service "openvpn" but still couldn't connect to `localhost 7505` via telnet. Yes, I'd added the line "management localhost 7505" to "server.ovpn" and that didn't help.

**UPDATE:**

I've finally connected by I can't connect to `localhost 7505` via telnet. Why?

I have this in my config:

```
management localhost 7505
```

and

```
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 7505: Connect failed
```

Answer (score 1):

To get up and running quickly I'd suggest installing either Virtualbox or Hyper-V and downloading the virtual appliance from [here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as-vm.html).  There's full instructions on how to get it up and running and it's a small download for a VM.  Plus, if you keep a copy the VHD you can mess it up as much as you like and just fire up another VM with the copy.

Comment: why would I care downloading and installing it again on the virtual machine as well as the virtual machine itself instead of finishing to set it up on my machine?

Comment: The virtual machine has the application already installed and ready to go.

Comment: that's not what I need

Comment: The OpenVPN management interface is really not meant for user interaction as It offers minimal user tools. In fact it is meant for other tasks see [THIS](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/management-interface.html)